# Implementing default value for HashMap

Tags: java

I do not want to use methods like MAP.getOrDefault since it requires the default definition every time the MAP is accessed which is not the behavior I want. I want to store a default value to my `HashMap` whenever a call to my `MAP` constant does not have a value associated with the key that is passed. This is what I have implemented:

```
public class Constants {

    public static final Map<String, String> MAP = DefaultHashMap.initMap();

    private static class DefaultHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
       
       private static Map<String, String> initMap() {
          Map<String, String> MAP = new DefaultHashMap<>("Default");
          MAP.put("Maria", "Hi");
          MAP.put("Alex", "Hi2");
          // I want to initialize this map to a default value if the key that is being used is not found
          return Collections.unmodifiableMap(MAP);
       }

       private V defaultValue;

       private DefaultHashMap(V defaultValue) {
          this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
       }

       @Override
       public V get(Object k) {
          return containsKey(k) ? super.get(k) : defaultValue;
       }
}
}

public class Outside {
    
    public void someMethod() {
       String value = Constants.MAP.get("key");
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't Java maps already have a getOrDefault()?

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I do not want to use methods like MAP.getOrDefault since it requires the default definition every time the MAP is accessed which is not the behavior I want.

Comment: Yeah, but why implement your own way of defaulting (ternaries) when you could just use the built-in method?

Comment: Secondly, this way of implementing defaulting prevents you from having different defaults for different keys.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I am not understanding? If the situation arises where I do need to have a different default value then I can just do `Constants.MAP.getOrDefault("none", "New Default")`

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html, which `implements Map<String, String>` and allows you to set defaults in the constructor?

Comment: @EricStein Can you provide a link of an example? I haven't used that class before so I wasn't aware of it

Answer (score 6):

There are some situations where this class's behaviour can be surprising.

- Should `map.containsValue(defaultValue)` be true or false?
- `map.put(key, value)` returns the old value associated with that key. If there was no such value, the current implementation returns `null` - is that correct, or should it have returned the default value? (the same can be asked for other methods like `replace`, `putIfAbsent`, `remove`, etc)
- Similarly, `map.compute(key, someFunction)` will pass `null` rather than the default value to `someFunction` if there is no value associated with `key`, meaning that while for `Map`s in general these two methods are equivalent, they are not equivalent when using a `DefaultMap` with no value associated with `key`:

```java
public static void doRounding1(Map<String, Double> map, String key) {
    map.put(Math.floor(map.get(key)));
}

public static void doRounding2(Map<String, Double> map, String key) {
    map.compute(key, Math::floor);
}
```

- Also, while I think `equals` is *formally* correct, the fact that `map1.equals(map2)` does not guarantee `map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key))` feels off

Honestly, with how hard it can be to subclass a class that doesn't go out of its way to document how to do so, I'd be tempted to just use a stock `HashMap` and take advantage of the existing `Map::getOrDefault` method. If we do need that tighter association between a map and a default value, it may still make more sense to provide some manner of composite that doesn't itself claim to implement the entire `Map` interface (but may still provide some utility functions). A simplified example of that might look like:

```java
public record DefaultMapping<KeyType, ValueType>(
    ValueType defaultValue,
    Map<KeyType, ValueType> map
) {
    public DefaultMapping(ValueType defaultValue, Map<KeyType, ValueType> map) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.map = new HashMap<>(map);
    }

    public ValueType get(KeyType key) {
        return map.getOrDefault(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: These are excellent concrete examples explaining why the "implicit default" is not a good approach. Another point to add to the list is that adding an implicit default simply breaks the Java Map API contract of the get-method, which explicitly says: "Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, *or null if this map contains no mapping for the key*."
(emphasis mine).

Comment: A very good idea to use a class which is NOT a Map to implement the desired behaviour!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    @Override
>    public V get(Object k) {
>       return containsKey(k) ? super.get(k) : defaultValue;
>    }
> ```

This is a possible implementation, but I would like to mention the `HashMap` method `V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`, which essentially does this already, but without the double lookup. Of course, there are other ways to avoid a double lookup, but `getOrDefault` is particularly simple to use here.

Comment: I do not want to use methods like MAP.getOrDefault since it requires the default definition every time the MAP is accessed which is not the behavior I want.

Comment: @user21476047 you can use it to implement your `get`.

Comment: Ohh sorry i understand now. I misread

Answer (score 0):

Alternative and improvements could be implemented.

Alternative implementation with instance initialisation block:

```
public class Constants {

    private static final Map<String, String> map = init("default value");
    private static final Map<String, String> init(String defaultValue) {
        
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap() {
            {
                put("some key", "some value");
                put("other key", "other value");
            }

            @Override
            public V get(Object k) {
                return containsKey(k) ? super.get(k) : defaultValue;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Improvement using static initialisation block and `computeIfAbsent` method available since Java version 1.8:

```
public class Constants {

    public static final Map<String, String> MAP = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        put("some key", "some value");
        put("other key", "other value");
    }
}

public class Outside {
    
    public void someMethod() {
       String value = Constants.MAP.computeIfAbsent("key", key -> "Default");
    }
}
```

Comment: First implementation you displayed is what I need however it has compile errors when I use it

Answer (score 0):

Why not having a specific `Constants` class with it's own methods rather than extending the `HashMap` class? In many cases it's better to prefer [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Maybe `get(String)` and `put(String, String)` are just enough. It will be easier to test and to maintain.

An other refactoring I would do to make it easier to test, is to have two constructors with or without the initial Map and the default value. So that you could instantiate the class in your tests.

If you really need to have a global instance of the `Constants` object either make `instance` public or have a method to access it. With the later option, you can delay the construction of the object until the first use if needed.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Constants {

    private static final Constants instance = new Constants("my default value");

    public static Constants instance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private final Map<String, String> constants;
    private final String defaultValue;

    public Constants(String defaultValue) {
        this.constants = new HashMap<>();
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public Constants(Map<String, String> constants, String defaultValue) {
        this.constants = new HashMap<>(constants);
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return constants.getOrDefault(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        constants.put(key, value);
    }
}

public class Outside {
    
    public void someMethod() {
       String value = Constants.instance().get("key");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Java used version includes `Optional` alternatively to override `get` method of `HashMap` just wrap the call of it with `Optional` and for convenience add a constant for default value...

```
Optional.ofNullable(Constants.MAP.get("key")).orElse(Constants.MAP_DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Following is an addendum to the previous answer with instance initialisation, `new HashMap() { ... }` defining and instantiating an anonymous class extending `HashMap` results in a new class being defined every time the method encapsulating the code is called. Intensive calling of the method and holding reference to the returned instances so they survive garbage collection could result in memory overload.

Comment: This does qualify as abusing Optionals: "Our intention was to provide a limited mechanism *for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result"*, and using null for such was overwhelmingly likely to cause errors." Allocating an object in order to make an if-else statement, is fairly inefficient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555